# What are the data types of social integration platforms (facebook, twitter, openid) ids?

Tags: database, postgresql, types, social-networking

I'm currently setting up a new users data model. Are the ids from facebook, twitter and openid all numerical? What is the length?

This is what i have so far:

[table users http://ojs.at/users.png](http://ojs.at/users.png)

Thanks for any collection.

Oliver

Comment: GUID perhaps... since they have to be unique...

Comment: columns are unique (the erm doesn't show it)

Answer (score 1):

OpenID identities are strings (URLs). There is no such thing as "OpenID id".

As for twitter and facebook, they use OAuth, and use strings(access tokens) too.

Comment: oh i see, how long can a OpenID url and OAuth strings be?

Comment: There is no theoretical limit. As I've said, OpenID identities are URL-s, and an url can have arbitrary length. In practice however, 256 characters would be more than necessary. I don't know about OAuth strings, but I think they're similar. Maybe you should look at examples in your OAuth library?

Comment: Since the tags indicate you're on PostgreSQL, you really should treat them as unlimited - use the "text" datatype. There's no drawback to it compared to varchar(nn), and since your datamodel doesn't have a limit, your implementation shouldn't.